# IAM Policy to give readonly access to a specific DBCluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM Managed Policy to assign to QA users that will give them readonly access to a specific DBCluster, the QA cluster.

So far I haven't been able to limit the access to the specific cluster, I can only get it to work if the `Resource` tag is set to all

```
"PolicyDocument": {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "rds:Describe*",
        "rds:ListTagsForResource"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "DescribeQADatabase"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried changing the `Resource` tag to my specific DBCluster ARN, but when I do that nothing shows in the RDS page in the AWS Console

Side question, if I look at the AWS Provided `AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess` I see that it gives access to a bunch of other AWS Resources like ec2 instances. Is there a document/resource I can use that will basically tell me all the dependencies I will need if I want to give access to a specific resource?

Comment: Console access will require bunch of permissions. Programmatic access would be easier to control and manage.

Comment: @Marcin unfortunately that's not going to be an option. We are using a serverless cluster  and we would need an ec2 instance for the users to ssh tunnel a client to the cluster. The plan is to just have these users user the query editor in the console for simplicity.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know which permissions would comprise minimum set required. I think its a trial-and-see approach to determine them.